# how can I get the content of a Web page as a string so I can print it somwhere else using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    var xmlhttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
      {
        return xmlhttp.responceText;
      }
    }
    this.model.result = xmlhttp.onreadystatechange;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", this.model.konfig, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: If you wish to load external page via link and read it as string, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779467/html-source-code-of-external-webpage-as-string

Comment: @Rajesh, not even remotely close.

Comment: And if you just wish to open some page in some div of your page, you can look into `iFrames`.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the HTML content of any node with `innerHTML`.
Example (for `body` node):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML
```