# jQuery Tabs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I don't know why this doesn't work, although it should:

```
$('#group-tabs').tabs({
    iframe: true,
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
            $("#test").load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Slightly older versions (jquery 1.8.x and jquery-ui 1.9.x)

http://jsfiddle.net/QGZZT/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to change your javascript, you were accessing the wrong elements:

```
$('#group-tabs').tabs({
    iframe: true,
    beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
        $('a').click(function() {
            alert(this.href);
            $(".tab-content").load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Ref.  http://jsfiddle.net/QGZZT/2/

However, I don't believe you are able to do what you want, because "Due to browser restrictions, most Ajax requests are subject to the "same origin policy"."

Ref.  [Cannot load an external page with jQuery.load into a div in my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059302/cannot-load-an-external-page-with-jquery-load-into-a-div-in-my-page)

You can; however, try using $.get or simply changing the source of an iFrame (very easy).

Comment: I'm just using iframe for the example, the pages I'm loading are on the same domain. I corrected the elements but still it doesn't work

Comment: Did you change `load` to `beforeLoad` like mine?

Comment: You would have to post your changes on jsfiddle in order for me to check it out.  Custom scripts for tabs should be pretty easy and not a bad option, just change the iFrame `src` when they click `id='http://mywebsite.com'`, etc.