# Load a website and modify with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Say a website exists with the following content.

```
<html><wrapper><div>Stuff I care about</div>Stuff I don't care about</wrapper></html>
```

Is it possible to load the website with javascript but also modify the content. So in this case I want to use Javascript to load the Stuff I care about, but hide everything else.(Kind of like an iframe... with benefits).

Note: To give you some context I'm trying to make an app that creates my own custom version of another persons website. *What makes this really difficult is part of the content I want to show is a form with a captcha*.

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively load content from a url into another element as follows, though I'm not sure about cross-domain issues:

```
$('target').load('http://www.example.com/index.html wrapper div');
```

Note that the part after the url ("wrapper div") is just a jQuery selector.

Also note that comments are right about the cross-domain issue. You'd either have to proxy www.example.com or [use YQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059302/cannot-load-an-external-page-with-jquery-load-into-a-div-in-my-page/5059320#5059320) (which I'm not familiar with).

Comment: Can't even get the following to work: $('body').load("http://google.com/"); *Note went to a site running jQuery and pasted code in Javascript console to test*

Comment: @PhilipK Cross site scripting rules.

Comment: Possible problem + solution to my last comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/5059320/773263

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to request and download the page using your server, then send it back to the client with AJAX.