# External href URL within jQuery ScrollTo Menu

Tags: jquery, menu, href

I have a problem with a jquery menu. I want one of the the menu links to go to an external site and not a frame within the slides. At present is just opens a blank frame on TEST3.

How would I get it to open an external URL within the same page?

There is a test page located here to understand the issue. http://www.vendvalor.com

```
<section class="content">
        <nav class="main-menu big">
            <a data-id="Test1" href="javascript:void(0)">Test1</a>
            <a data-id="Test2" href="javascript:void(0)">Test2</a>
            <a data-id="Test3" href="http://www.google.com">Test3</a>
            <a data-id="Test4" href="javascript:void(0)">Test4</a>                    
        </nav>
```

Comment: check this link : https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

Comment: or see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059302/cannot-load-an-external-page-with-jquery-load-into-a-div-in-my-page