# How to display php on html

Tags: php, html

I have a simple website that has two columns. One for the `maincontent` and on the right a small column `div class="login"` that has a login form. There is a link there named `register`. When the user clicks it he gets sent to `createuser.php`. What i want is for that entire `createuser.php` page to be displayed inside the `div` called `maincontent`: how would i do that?

The div:

```
<div id="maincontent">
i want the `createuser.php` (just a form inside it) displayed here so i assume there
has to be something like <?php include 'createuser.php' ?> inside here but only
display it after the user has clicked "register"-button.
</div>
```

I do not want to use ajax.

Comment: Try AJAX.... It can help

Comment: "This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself."

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440241/load-div-content-from-one-page-and-show-it-to-another). It might help you

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Are you looking for a way to include ``createuser.php`` into another page? Then templating (search for it) might what you are looking for. In any case: Please make your question more specific! You can always edit your question (or leave a comment). The issue people are having is that it is not entirely clear what your problem is, but hopefully we can get this sorted out.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use AJAX? You realise the page has to reload if you don't want to use AJAX, right?

Answer (score 1):

Are you willing to use jQuery?

```
$("#id_of_register_link").click(function() {
  $("#maincontent").load("path/to/createuser.php");
});
```